# Javascript: How can I modify attributesof a class if one class exists?

Tags: javascript, css, class

I'm trying to get my script to change the style for an element on only one page. I thought maybe the best way of doing this would be to detect and see if there is an id unique to the page (`profile-advanced-details`) and if there is, then modify the other id (`page-body`) height to 1500px.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work... is my syntax wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("page-body");

if (!document.getElementsById('profile-advanced-details').length){
  return;  //if profile-advanced-details doesn't exist, do nothing
}

else {
  wrap.style.height = "1500px";//if it does exist, change the height of page-body
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: if(document.getElementById('profile-advanced-details').length <= 0) {}

Answer (score 0):

`id`s are unique. There is no such method as `document.getElementsById()`. use `document.getElementById()` instead, which will either return the element with the specified `id` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is singular, not plural. you also don't need `.length` because it means something different depending on the node.

```
if( document.getElementById('profile-advanced-details')) {
  document.getElementById('page-body').style.height = "1500px";
}
```

You might also be able to use CSS, but only if the reference element ("profile-advanced-details") is BEFORE the target ("page-body"). This probably isn't the case here, but it's a good trick to know:

```css
#profile-advanced-details + #page-body,
    #profile-advanced-details + * page-body {height:1500px}
/* the following may work in CSS4: */
!#page-body #profile-advanced-details,
    !#page_body + #profile-advanced-details,
    !#page_body + * #profile-advanced-details {height:1500px}
$#page-body #profile-advanced-details,
    $#page_body + #profile-advanced-details,
    $#page_body + * #profile-advanced-details {height:1500px}
#page-body! #profile-advanced-details,
    #page_body! + #profile-advanced-details,
    #page_body! + * #profile-advanced-details {height:1500px}
#page-body$ #profile-advanced-details,
    #page_body$ + #profile-advanced-details,
    #page_body$ + * #profile-advanced-details {height:1500px}
/* The different ones are partially because I don't remember the spec,
          but mostly because it's changing */
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("page-body");

if (document.getElementById('profile-advanced-details')){
    // profile-advanced-details does exist
    wrap.style.height = "1500px";
}
```

This works because the getElementById of 'profile-advanced-details' will return null if it doesn't exist which means the condition doesn't evaluate to true and the code within it won't be called.

Comment: because unfortunately I cannot modify the html directly. I can only add scripts and css that will be displayed across all pages.

Comment: In that case the above will work, although if you have multiple elements with the same id, I think someone else mentioned that you should indeed be using class names instead. Then you can use the function 'getElementsByClassName'. But for the record if you have more than one element with the same id then 'getElementById' should return the first one found, but don't rely on this as it's not supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since Element ids are unique, you should rather give your elements the classname `'profile-advanced-details'` and use `document.getElementsByClassName` to check if one exists

So with the code you provided this woiuld look like this:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("page-body");

if (document.getElementsByClassName('profile-advanced-details').length == 0){
  return;  //if profile-advanced-details doesn't exist, do nothing
}

else {
  wrap.style.height = "1500px";//if it does exist, change the height of page-body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say class, right? then change

```
         if (!document.getElementsById('profile-advanced-details').length)
```

to

```
         if (!document.getElementByClass('profile-advanced-details').length)
```